# Force target printer in Java

Tags: java, printing

Is there a way to force the target printer in java, using HashPrintRequestAttributeSet ?

I don't want the user to be able to change the printer in the printdialog

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Had to figure this out the hard way, but for the future generations, here's some of my 
code:

```
PrintService[] printServices;
PrintService printService;
PageFormat pageFormat;

String printerName = "Your printer name in Devices and Printers";

PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, printServiceAttributeSet);

pageFormat = new PageFormat(); // If you want to adjust heigh and width etc. of your paper.
pageFormat = printerjob.defaultPage();

PrinterJob printerjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

printerjob.setPrintable(new Server(), pageFormat); // Server was my class's name, you use yours.

try {
    printService = printServices[0];
    printerjob.setPrintService(printService); // Try setting the printer you want
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: No printer named '" + printerName + "', using default printer.");
    pageFormat = printerjob.defaultPage(); // Set the default printer instead.
} catch (PrinterException exception) {
    System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
}

try {
    printerjob.print(); // Actual print command
} catch (PrinterException exception) {
    System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

My code to solve this :

```
String printerNameDesired = "My Printer";

PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of printers
DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;

int count = service.length;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerNameDesired)) {
        docPrintJob = service[i].createPrintJob();
        i = count;
    }
}
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pjob.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());
pjob.setJobName("job");
pjob.print();
```

Comment: This one worked for me, only you forgot to initialize the docPrintJob. I suggest to add the following code to make it fully functional: `DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;` after `PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by running cmd command in Java

```
static void changeWindowsDefaultPrinter(String printerName) {
    String cmdLine  = String.format("RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n \"%s\"", printerName);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", cmdLine );
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = null;
    try { p = builder.start(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = new String();
    while (true) {
        try {
            line = r.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println( "result  "  + line);
    }
}
```

And It's Wroked for Me :D