# Change google chrome default printer, programmatically

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applet

I am developing a **web application** (only has to work in the **latest Chrome**) that prints different content to **different printers**.

What I need is to have the ability to change the default Chrome printer programmatically.

I searched for a **javascript** solution, it seems there is no such one.

I searched for **Google Chrome extension**, also not availabe. ( a firefox extension is available)

I tried to develop Google Chrome extension using **native messaging**, I prepared the extension, but this solution and the native application would be so **complicated**, due to setup prerequisites (the extension and the native app) and also the complexity of printing HTML/CSS content from this native app.

my question is about the ability to do so using ***any other possible solution*** as:

- flash **actionscript 3**
- **java applet**

flash **actionscript 3** would be **better**, as it is preinstalled
   with Chrome.

thanks is advance

Answer (score 2):

AS3 has a [PrintJob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html) class for printing, however, only the AIR runtime has methods to [get a list of printers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printers), and [set the printer programmatically](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printer).

For a Java applet approach, see ["Force target printer in Java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177531/force-target-printer-in-java).

Comment: thanks, I am trying with java applet, I'll post the code as soon as I finish it (and of course accept the answer).

Comment: Till now all I can do with Java is to print to a specific printer (print from Java not from chrome).
I cannot change chrome or system default printer.
this may be an alternate temporary solution till I ( or someone else) figure out a better and more straightforward one. I can send the the simpler  print task to Java, while the other and more complicated to chrome default printer.
Still refining my code ... (so busy these days :( )