# Print in Java without changing default printer - Windows 10

Tags: java, printing, default

i am printing something with java and i noticed that my Systemwide Defaultprinter changes to the printer i used the last time. Why is that? 
My programm shouldnt do that. Any Ideas?

```
        String printerNameDesired = "Adobe PDF";
    PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of printers
    DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;
    int count = service.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerNameDesired))
        {
            docPrintJob = service[i].createPrintJob();
            i = count;
        }
    }
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    try
    {
        job.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());
    }
    catch (PrinterException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldPrinter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    int margin = 0;
    paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin * 2, paper.getHeight() - margin * 2);
    pf.setPaper(paper);

    job.setPrintable(this, pf);
    //boolean ok = job.printDialog(); //ruft den auswahl-dialog auf
    try
    {
        job.print();
    }
    catch (PrinterException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldPrinter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The printerservice lastly used at "job.print();" is set as the defaultprinter in Windows "Devices and Printers".
Tnaks for any help

Comment: Have a look at [this possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177531/force-target-printer-in-java)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not a Java bug, but a Win 10 feature, which can be switched off with:

```
Start(Window)Icon/Settings/Devices/Printers & scanners/Let Windows manage my
default printer: Off
```

Or, on a German Windows:

```
Start(Window)Icon/Einstellungen/Geräte/Drucker & Scanner/Standarddrucker von
Windows verwalten lassen: Aus
```